# redirect external ads link by php and seo

Tags: php, redirect, seo, pagerank, ads

approximately i have read all questions asked at SO but didn't get my answer!
i need to know whats the best method to make Search Engine friendly redirection an external  advertisement link with PHP? for example for link to a site we have a url in our site:
`http://www.oursite.com/ads.php?ad=1`
and must be redirect to this:
`httP://www.somesite.com`
how we can redirect it without lost PR or Search Engine trust?!

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `rel="nofollow"`. In fact, Google requires it for paid links.
2. Block the redirect script with robots.txt or the `x-robots` HTTP header tag